# Evaluating radius of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

Find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{27}\right)^n(x-3)^{3n+2}$$

Attempt:

I set $d_{3n} = 0$, $d_{3n+1} = 0$, $d_{3n+2} = a_n$, $d_{3n+3} = 0$

Hence the series becomes $\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n(x-3)^n$

Now, its given that $R=\limsup(b_n)^{1/n}$ in the book

here, $R=\limsup(d_n)^{1/n}=\limsup(a_n)^{3/(n-2)}$

That is, $R=\limsup\left(\frac{-1}{27}\right)^{3n/(n-2)}$

How will I proceed further? (How can I evaluate the lim sup)

Comment: First, I think it is actually $$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup b_n^{1/n}$$ Second: $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} d_n^{1/n}=\limsup\limits_{m\to\infty} a_{m}^{1/(3m+2)}$$

Comment: Also, be careful to add in  the absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

Letting
$y = x-3$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{27}\right)^n(x-3)^{3n+2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{27}\right)^ny^{3n+2}\\
&=y^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{27}\right)^n(y^3)^n\\
\end{array}
$

so,
by the root test,
this converges when
$|y^3/27| < 1$
and diverges when
$|y^3/27| > 1$.
This is equivalent to
$|y/3| < 1$
and
$|y/3| > 1$
or
$|x-3| < 3$
to converge
and
$|x-3| > 3$
to diverge.